Editing 3D model in Altium
Would you please let me know how can I edit a 3D model for Altium?
I want to do it in Altium not with a second party software. For example in this example this pins are too long and I want to make them a bit shorter:

Regards,

What feedback did you get from any of the Altium support sites?

@ Andy aka I coud not find any Altium related froum acctually, the official Altium froum apparently is not working

Try one called discord altium. I know it's quite well used.

@Andromeda Literally the upper result on google for the search "altium forum" takes you to
https://forum.live.altium.com/. It is available for free, you just need a user account.

Altium does (fortunately) not have a 3D file editor, as it's not an MCAD tool.
There are a plethora of free and non-free MCAD tools with basic shape editing abilities, It's not relevant to suggest one or the other here. (Maybe ask engineering stackexchange, if that's relevant over there)
The possibility you have if you are adamant on using only Altium is to recreate the shape based on the built in modeling feature, using simple extruded, spherical and cylindrical 3D shapes.
A led like that is built up from a cylinder with a sphere on top, and two square legs protruding out from the bottom.
The specific instructions on how to do that is too long winded and version specific to explain in a simple answer, but you can get the information you need from the Altium Designer documentation.
Example image from the Altium Designer 24 documentation shows how they've recreated a TO-92 can based on the generic shapes, and that it can get fairly accurate for simple geometry.

